# Find top N elements with Go fixed capacity PriorityQueue

Tags: algorithm, go, heap, priority-queue

Trying to write my own Go PriorityQueue with fixed capacity using the https://pkg.go.dev/container/heap package, and translating the algorithm from
http://stevehanov.ca/blog/?id=122, noted below:

```
def heapSearch( bigArray, k ):
    heap = []
    # Note: below is for illustration. It can be replaced by 
    # heapq.nlargest( bigArray, k )
    for item in bigArray:
        # If we have not yet found k items, or the current item is larger than
        # the smallest item on the heap,
        if len(heap) < k or item > heap[0]:
            # If the heap is full, remove the smallest element on the heap.
            if len(heap) == k: heapq.heappop( heap )
            # add the current element as the new smallest.
            heapq.heappush( heap, item )
    return heap
```

I came up with this -- https://play.golang.org/p/VmPURbWSmIA

```golang
    for value, priority := range items {
        // If we have not yet found k items, or the current item is larger than
        // the smallest item on the heap,
        if len(pq) < k || value > pq[0].value {
            // If the heap is full, remove the smallest element on the heap.
            if len(pq) == k {
                pq.Pop()
            }
            // add the current element as the new smallest.
            pq.Push(&Item{
                value:    value,
                priority: priority,
            })
        }
        heap.Init(&pq)
    }
```

However, something is still off.
Would somebody help to correct it please?

PS. The `heap.Init(&pq)` was not in the loop before, but moved there because of [Priority queues in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809978/priority-queues-in-go) :

> Calling heap.Init(&pq) will sort the entire heap

PPS:

More failed attempts:

- https://play.golang.org/p/pete4rqv6ui
- https://play.golang.org/p/LsOl_9UtugU

Comment: The Python code finds the N largest items using a min-heap: i.e., in the heap, element 0 is the smallest because the heap property has h[i] < h[2i] and h[i] < h[2i+1] (modulo all the fiddly adjustments needed for 0 vs 1 based indexing). But you have a max-heap: h[i] > h[2i], etc. To find the N largest, you must build a min-heap, not a max-heap.

Comment: Besides this, to use the Go `heap` functions, you must call `heap.Push` and `heap.Pop`, not `pq.Push` and `pq.Pop`. Since you want to build a max-heap, you can still do this, you just want to force the new item into the heap if its priority exceeds the existing max priority. Unfortunately there's now no easy way to find the *minimum* item to drop.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more. Is this the min-heap that you talk about -- https://play.golang.org/p/WdUx8l9dvH1 @torek?

Comment: Well, yes, but you would normally use `<` for the `Less` function.

Comment: I tried `<` first, but that gave me index out of range error, :( :(

Comment: [Here's a min-heap variant of your first attempt](https://play.golang.org/p/9vHpQFnVzca). Since we only pop 4 of the 10 items in the queue, and it is a min-heap, we get items 11 through 14 inclusive.

Comment: To build the queue with the N largest items, but then later take them off the queue in higher-priority-first order, you can use two different heaps: a min-heap for collecting the items, and then a max-heap for working with them (or sort them in reverse order once you have them, if that's OK).

Comment: Er, "sort" is the wrong word there: I mean that if `h` is a min-heap of N items, then N calls to `heap.Pop(&h)` gets you those N items in smallest-to-largest order, so put those into your work list in reverse order and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from [Limit size of the priority queue for Go's heap interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065781/limit-size-of-the-priority-queue-for-gos-heap-interface-implementation)

which finds the minimum set.

To find the maximum set:

https://play.golang.org/p/MtZCXGcESeF

@torek has also given a working one, but I'll leave him to put his https://play.golang.org/p/9vHpQFnVzca answer himself, if he likes to.